# How to show tooltip on globe object from ThreeGlobe

Tags: reactjs, three.js, webgl, react-three-fiber

I have a Globe Component defined as shown below:

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import * as THREE from "three";
import { TrackballControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/TrackballControls";
import ThreeGlobe from "three-globe";

function GlobeComponent() {
  const globeElement = useRef();
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch GeoJSON data
    fetch(
      "//unpkg.com/three-globe/example/hexed-polygons/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.geojson"
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setCountries(data.features));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (countries && !globeElement.current.children.length) {
      // Create globe
      const globe = new ThreeGlobe()
        .globeImageUrl("//unpkg.com/three-globe/example/img/earth-dark.jpg")
        .hexPolygonsData(countries)
        .hexPolygonResolution(3)
        .hexPolygonMargin(0.3)
        .hexPolygonColor(
          () =>
            `#${Math.round(Math.random() * Math.pow(2, 24))
              .toString(16)
              .padStart(6, "0")}`
        )
        .labelText("Hello World!")
        .labelSize(15)
        .labelResolution(3);

      // Setup scene
      const scene = new THREE.Scene();

      // Add globe to scene
      scene.add(globe);

      // Add lights
      scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xbbbbbb, Math.PI));
      scene.add(new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.6 * Math.PI));

      // Setup renderer
      const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      globeElement.current.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

      // Setup camera
      const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera();

      // aspect ratio of the camera (width / height)
      camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      camera.position.z = 250;

      // Add camera controls
      const tbControls = new TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
      tbControls.minDistance = 101;
      tbControls.rotateSpeed = 5;
      tbControls.zoomSpeed = 0.5;

      // Kick-off renderer
      (function animate() {
        tbControls.update();
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      })();
    }
  }, [countries, globeElement]);

  return (
    <>
      <div ref={globeElement} />
    </>
  );
}

export default GlobeComponent;
```

I used this resource: https://github.com/vasturiano/three-globe/blob/master/example/hexed-polygons/index.html

I've been able to render the globe and have it show up with the polygons.

I tried to use `onPolygonHover` and `onHover` to show a tooltip when I hover over the polygons, but these methods do not seem to exist in three.

I also tried labelText, but the text did not appear on the polygons.

This is my first time working with threejs, and some guidance on what to look at would really help.

Thank you!